# How to add the value of my Sub-query, I want to add the value of Cash,Charge and Other_Charges as Total_payment

Tags: db2, subquery

I am using 2 tables, `TL_FISCALREPORT` and `TL_TENDER`. What I want to do is to add the total value of my 3 subqueries from `TL_TENDER` named as cash, charge, tender and *show it in my query*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.DT_TIME,F.DT_DATE,'DEPT STORE' AS CATEGORY,
      F.STOREID,F.TID,(F.CURRENT_POSITIVE) AS NEW_GT,
      PREV_POSITIVE,TOTAL_SALES_AMT,
      CAST((((F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT+F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT)/.80)*.20) AS DECIMAL(16,2)) AS        
      SC_DISC,(0) AS PWD_DISC,F.REGULAR_DISCOUNTS_AMOUNT,(0) as NON_PROMO_DISC,      
      (F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT+F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT+F.REGULAR_DISCOUNTS_AMOUNT) AS        
      TOTAL_DISC,F.NEW_GRAND_TOTAL_VOIDS,F.DAILY_RETURNS,(0) AS ADJ, 
      (TOTAL_SALES_AMT-(F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT+F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT+F.REGULAR_DISCOUNTS_AMOUNT)-0) AS GROSS_SALES ,      
      (F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT+F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT) AS  SC_SALES,(0) AS PWD_SALES,(F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT       
      +F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT+0) AS NON_VAT_SALES,F.ZERO_RATED_SALES_AMOUNT       
      ,CAST((F.DAILY_GROSS_SALES-F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT-F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT-       
      F.ZERO_RATED_SALES_AMOUNT/1.12)AS DECIMAL(12,1)) AS VATABLE_SALES,CAST(( ((F.DAILY_GROSS_SALES-       
       F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT-F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT-F.ZERO_RATED_SALES_AMOUNT)*.12)/1.12) AS DECIMAL(15,2)) AS        
       VAT,CAST((F.DAILY_GROSS_SALES-(F.DAILY_GROSS_SALES-F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT-       
       F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT-F.ZERO_RATED_SALES_AMOUNT*.12/1.12)) AS DECIMAL(12,1))       
       AS NETSALES,  
           (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(AMOUNT AS FLOAT ))   
               FROM TL_TENDER  
                  WHERE TL_TENDER.TID = F.tid AND TL_TENDER.NTND =1 and TL_TENDER.DT_DATE='2016-06-30' ) CASH,  
           (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(AMOUNT AS FLOAT))   
               FROM TL_TENDER  
                  WHERE TL_TENDER.TID = F.TID AND TL_TENDER.NTND =2  AND TL_TENDER.DT_DATE='2016-06-30') CHARGE,  
           (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(AMOUNT AS FLOAT))  
                FROM TL_TENDER  
                  WHERE TL_TENDER.TID = F.TID  AND TL_TENDER.NTND >=3 AND TL_TENDER.DT_DATE='2016-06-30') OTHER_TENDER  
,F.FROM_FISCAL_XACT,F.TO_FISCAL_XACT ,F.POS_ITEMS_COUNT,F.PREV_VOID_COUNT,(0) AS NOSALE_TRANSACTION,
F.REPORT_TYPE FROM TL_FISCALREPORT   F          
WHERE F.REPORT_TYPE=1 AND F.STOREID=1 AND F.DT_DATE ='2016-06-30' 
ORDER BY TID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add this as another column in the select list:

```
  (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(AMOUNT AS FLOAT ))   
               FROM TL_TENDER  
                  WHERE TL_TENDER.TID = F.tid AND TL_TENDER.NTND =1 and TL_TENDER.DT_DATE='2016-06-30' ) +  
           (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(AMOUNT AS FLOAT))   
               FROM TL_TENDER  
                  WHERE TL_TENDER.TID = F.TID AND TL_TENDER.NTND =2  AND TL_TENDER.DT_DATE='2016-06-30') +   
           (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(AMOUNT AS FLOAT))  
                FROM TL_TENDER  
                  WHERE TL_TENDER.TID = F.TID  AND TL_TENDER.NTND >=3 AND TL_TENDER.DT_DATE='2016-06-30') AS YOURTOTAL
```

Giving:

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.DT_TIME,F.DT_DATE,'DEPT STORE' AS CATEGORY,
      F.STOREID,F.TID,(F.CURRENT_POSITIVE) AS NEW_GT,
      PREV_POSITIVE,TOTAL_SALES_AMT,
      CAST((((F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT+F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT)/.80)*.20) AS DECIMAL(16,2)) AS        
      SC_DISC,(0) AS PWD_DISC,F.REGULAR_DISCOUNTS_AMOUNT,(0) as NON_PROMO_DISC,      
      (F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT+F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT+F.REGULAR_DISCOUNTS_AMOUNT) AS        
      TOTAL_DISC,F.NEW_GRAND_TOTAL_VOIDS,F.DAILY_RETURNS,(0) AS ADJ, 
      (TOTAL_SALES_AMT-(F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT+F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT+F.REGULAR_DISCOUNTS_AMOUNT)-0) AS GROSS_SALES ,      
      (F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT+F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT) AS  SC_SALES,(0) AS PWD_SALES,(F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT       
      +F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT+0) AS NON_VAT_SALES,F.ZERO_RATED_SALES_AMOUNT       
      ,CAST((F.DAILY_GROSS_SALES-F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT-F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT-       
      F.ZERO_RATED_SALES_AMOUNT/1.12)AS DECIMAL(12,1)) AS VATABLE_SALES,CAST(( ((F.DAILY_GROSS_SALES-       
       F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT-F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT-F.ZERO_RATED_SALES_AMOUNT)*.12)/1.12) AS DECIMAL(15,2)) AS        
       VAT,CAST((F.DAILY_GROSS_SALES-(F.DAILY_GROSS_SALES-F.SC5_DISC_AMOUNT-       
       F.SC20_DISC_AMOUNT-F.ZERO_RATED_SALES_AMOUNT*.12/1.12)) AS DECIMAL(12,1))       
       AS NETSALES,  
           (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(AMOUNT AS FLOAT ))   
               FROM TL_TENDER  
                  WHERE TL_TENDER.TID = F.tid AND TL_TENDER.NTND =1 and TL_TENDER.DT_DATE='2016-06-30' ) CASH,  
           (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(AMOUNT AS FLOAT))   
               FROM TL_TENDER  
                  WHERE TL_TENDER.TID = F.TID AND TL_TENDER.NTND =2  AND TL_TENDER.DT_DATE='2016-06-30') CHARGE,  
           (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(AMOUNT AS FLOAT))  
                FROM TL_TENDER  
                  WHERE TL_TENDER.TID = F.TID  AND TL_TENDER.NTND >=3 AND TL_TENDER.DT_DATE='2016-06-30') OTHER_TENDER  
,F.FROM_FISCAL_XACT,F.TO_FISCAL_XACT ,F.POS_ITEMS_COUNT,F.PREV_VOID_COUNT,(0) AS NOSALE_TRANSACTION,
F.REPORT_TYPE,
      (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(AMOUNT AS FLOAT ))   
                   FROM TL_TENDER  
                      WHERE TL_TENDER.TID = F.tid AND TL_TENDER.NTND =1 and TL_TENDER.DT_DATE='2016-06-30' ) +  
               (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(AMOUNT AS FLOAT))   
                   FROM TL_TENDER  
                      WHERE TL_TENDER.TID = F.TID AND TL_TENDER.NTND =2  AND TL_TENDER.DT_DATE='2016-06-30') +   
               (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(AMOUNT AS FLOAT))  
                    FROM TL_TENDER  
                      WHERE TL_TENDER.TID = F.TID  AND TL_TENDER.NTND >=3 AND TL_TENDER.DT_DATE='2016-06-30') AS YOURTOTAL
 FROM TL_FISCALREPORT   F          
WHERE F.REPORT_TYPE=1 AND F.STOREID=1 AND F.DT_DATE ='2016-06-30' 
ORDER BY TID
```